# Kendo grid ajax vs server dropdown

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, kendo-grid

Can someone enlighten me on the difference between Kendo grid AJAX binding and server binding using Ajax() and Server() methods respectively (on Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.DataSourceBuilder)?

This question is especially in the context of a dropdown column I would like to have in the grid.

In keeping with the spirit of Stack Exchange, I am not seeking opinions, but actual differences and when I could use which.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a kendo Razorgrid then I have two approaches. Normally a dropdownlist will be a foreign key, so for the example let us pretend it is a person in the grid and you want a department dropdown.

If you have all departments in a viewbag then you can bind immidiatly:

```
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.DepartmentId, ((IEnumerable<Department>)ViewData["Departments"]), "Id", "Name");
```

But if you want a dynamic dropdown then you will do it with JavaScript. E.g. in the grid make an onedit method and then in the JavaScript method do the binding

```
    var departmentDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
    {
        transport: {
            read: { url: "department/getlist" },
            parameterMap: function(data, action) {
                var newParams = { parentId: e.model.PublisherId };
                return newParams;
            }
        }
    });
    $("#DepartmentId").data("kendoDropDownList").setDataSource(departmentDataSource);
```